# How to write a Scala parser for paths?

Tags: scala, parsing, path

I am a beginner in scala writing a scala parser in which I need to parse a path like this (suppose x is an integer):
/hfds://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/path1/path2/filename1.jpg

I tried the following not sure if I am on the right track:

```
  def pathIdent: Parser[String] = ("/hdfs""+"""(\d+~\.\d*)"""+ ~("""(u[a-zA-Z0-9])*+"""+"\.[\\'"jpg]"").r
```

I know it has errors! I really need help on this!

Comment: what do you want to extract from the paths? You can can just institute a hadoop path and let the Path class handle all the parsing stuff. Can can explain more of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I am writing a parser which is going to read a path an operand and another path or an integer number and then after syntax checking it should send the expression for calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You regex looks like it has typos. Try with something like this:

```
scala> val regex = """^/hfds://([\d\.]+):(\d+)/([\w/]+/(\w+\.\w+)$)""".r
regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = ^/hfds://([\d\.]+):(\d+)/([\w/]+/(\w+\.\w+)$)
```

Some sample path:

```
scala> val path = """/hfds://111.222.33.444:5555/path1/path2/filename1.jpg"""
path: String = /hfds://111.222.33.444:5555/path1/path2/filename1.jpg
```

Then do the matching:

```
scala> val regex(numbers,afterColon,fullPath,filename) = path
numbers: String = 111.222.33.444
afterColon: String = 5555
fullPath: String = path1/path2/filename1.jpg
filename: String = filename1.jpg
```

To catch parsing errors you can use pattern matching like this, e.g. parsing the filename:

```
def parseFilename(path: String): Option[String] = path match {
     case regex(numbers,afterColon,fullPath,filename) => Some(filename)
     case _ => println("parse error");None
}
```

It will return a Option of that filename:

```
scala> parseFilename(path)
res0: Option[String] = Some(filename1.jpg)

scala> val badPath="""/hfds://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/path1/path2/filename1.jpg"""
badPath: String = /hfds://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/path1/path2/filename1.jpg

scala> parseFilename(badPath)
parse error
res1: Option[String] = None
```

Comment: Thank you for your brief explanation :-)

Comment: I have added it into my parser but when I run it I have this error: [1.1] failure: `(' expected but `h' found
any opinion?

Comment: would you please help me on this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30836294/3827280  I am really devastated can't figure it out!

Comment: that questions' answer is accepted. So what exactly is unclear?

Comment: Actually the error is still there and it's not solved yet!