# How to define a Regex in StandardTokenParsers to identify path?

Tags: regex, scala, parsing, lexical-analysis

I am writing a parser in which I want to parse arithmetic expressions like:
/hdfs://xxx.xx.xx.x:xxxx/path1/file1.jpg+1 
I want to parse it change the infix to postfix and do the calculation. I used helps from a part of [code in another discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14242090/3827280) as well.

```
 class InfixToPostfix extends StandardTokenParsers {
 import lexical._

 def regexStringLit(r: Regex): Parser[String] = acceptMatch(
 "string literal matching regex " + r,
 { case  StringLit(s)  if r.unapplySeq(s).isDefined => s })
 def pathIdent: Parser[String] =regexStringLit("/hdfs://([\d\.]+):(\d+)/([\w/]+/(\w+\.\w+))".r)
 lexical.delimiters ++= List("+","-","*","/", "^","(",")",",")
 def value :Parser[Expr] = numericLit ^^ { s => Number(s) }
def variable:Parser[Expr] =  pathIdent ^^ { s => Variable(s) }
def parens:Parser[Expr] = "(" ~> expr <~ ")"

def argument:Parser[Expr] = expr <~ (","?)
def func:Parser[Expr] = ( pathIdent ~ "(" ~ (argument+) ~ ")" ^^ { case f ~ _ ~ e ~ _ => Function(f, e) })

def term = (value | parens | func | variable)

// Needed to define recursive because ^ is right-associative
def pow :Parser[Expr] = ( term ~ "^" ~ pow ^^ {case left ~ _ ~ right => BinaryOperator(left, "^", right) }|
            term)
def factor = pow * ("*" ^^^ { (left:Expr, right:Expr) => BinaryOperator(left, "*", right) } |
                    "/" ^^^ { (left:Expr, right:Expr) => BinaryOperator(left, "/", right) } )
def sum =  factor * ("+" ^^^ { (left:Expr, right:Expr) => BinaryOperator(left, "+", right) } |
                    "-" ^^^ { (left:Expr, right:Expr) => BinaryOperator(left, "-", right) } )
def expr = ( sum | term )

def parse(s:String) = {

   val tokens = new lexical.Scanner(s)
    phrase(expr)(tokens)
}
```

//and the rest of the code

I was able to solve the following errors with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30854228/3827280):

```
      ScalaParser.scala:192: invalid escape character
  [error]     def pathIdent: Parser[String] =regexStringLit("/hdfs://([\d\.]+):(\d+)/([\w/]+/(\w+\.\w+))".r)
  [error]                                                               ^
  [error] ScalaParser.scala:192: invalid escape character
  [error]     def pathIdent: Parser[String] =regexStringLit("/hdfs://([\d\.]+):(\d+)/([\w/]+/(\w+\.\w+))".r)
   [error]                                                                ^
   [error] ScalaParser.scala:192: invalid escape character
   [error]     def pathIdent: Parser[String] =regexStringLit("/hdfs://([\d\.]+):(\d+)/([\w/]+/(\w+\.\w+))".r)
   [error]                                                                        ^
```

With the change of pathIdent to this:

```
  def pathIdent: Parser[String] =regexStringLit("/hdfs://([\\d.]+):(\\d+)/([\\w/]+/(\\w+\\.w+))".r)
```

Now I am getting a run time error which says:

```
 [1.1] failure: string literal matching regex /hdfs://([\d\.]+):(\d+)/([\w/]+/(\w+\.\w+)) expected

/hdfs://111.33.55.2:8888/folder1/p.a3d+1
^
```

It was working using JavaTokenParsers but with current changes and I had to use StandardTokenParsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a double quoted string backslash is an escape character. If you mean to use the literal backslash in a double quotes string you must escape it, thus `"\d"` should be `"\\d"`.

Furthermore you do not need to escape the regex dot within a character class, since dot has no special meaning with a character class. So `"[\d.]"` should just be "[\d.]".

You can also forgo all this escaping business by using the raw interpolator or multi-line string literals using triple quotes.

Comment: Thank you, I do have the same problem with the "w" and "." in the : (\w+\.\w+) should I write it as (\\w+\\.w+)?

Comment: Now I am getting new error says :" not found: type Regex " in the line :  def regexStringLit(r: Regex): Parser[String] = acceptMatch(...

Comment: You do not need to escape backslash, just when you use double quote per default combinations like \n (new line) have special meaning to Java/Scala at compile time, thus if you mean the use literal string \n you can either "\\n" or use """\n""". Regex has its own special character like \d and \w which are parsed at run-time, so for the regex to work you must use literal \d and literal \w.

Comment: So I fixed it to : "/hdfs://([\\d.]+):(\\d+)/([\\w/]+/(\\w+\\.w+))".r now I am getting this error: not found: type Regex ", in the line : def regexStringLit(r: Regex): Parser[String] Why it's not a Regex?

Comment: You have to import it: `import scala.util.matching.Regex`

Comment: Sorry I forgot that part but now I have the runtime error saying : [1.1] failure: string literal matching regex /hdfs://([\d.]+):(\d+)/([\w/]+/(\w+\.w+)) expected